# Brightcove smart player media controls button quality

Tags: brightcove

Have just completed an implementation for brightcove on the following site: www.disney.com.au.

We have a brightcove player running for some of the items in the main header slidershow. We're using the smart api and when viewed in on desktop(flash) I noticed that some controls in the player are a little blurry. It looks vert similar to an old flash issue where certain items we're blurry if they weren't positioned on a full pixel x,y value.

We cannot use the 'flat' brightcove theme and would prefer not to have to create a custom skin if avoidable. Any idea how to fix this issue ?

Cheers